# MS Access SQL: Mapping different IDs in a query?

Tags: sql, database, ms-access-2010

A benchmark database stores questionnaire questions in one table and the participants responses to those questions in another table. For each year, new tables were created, and over the years, question IDs changed. Thus, it became difficult to generate one joined table of all responses over all years because the question IDs do not match anymore (for example, in 2010, the question "material cost" had question ID "bp2.12" but in the 2011 benchmarking study it became question ID "bp2.16" because new questions were added). However, the question table also stores a mapping to the old question ID.

What SQL query (MS Access SQL) generates a table with all responses of all participants for two years with the correct mapping?

Base tables (with sample data):

- tbl_questions_2010: ID | questiontext | unit

  - bp2.12 | material cost | USD
  - bp2.13 | personnel cost | USD
  - bp2.14 | FTE | FTE
  - ...
- tbl_questions_2011: ID | questiontext | unit | 2010_ID

  - bp2.16 | material cost | USD | bp2.12
  - bp2.20 | personnel cost | USD | bp2.13
  - bp2.21 | FTE | FTE | bp2.14
- tbl_responses_2010: ID | question_ID | participant_ID | response

  - 1 | bp2.12 | 1 | 2,289,990
  - ...
- tbl_responses_2011: ID | question_ID | participant_ID | response

  - 78 | bp2.16 | 3 | 723,091
  - ...
- tbl_participants: ID | participant_name

  - 1 | ACME LTD.
  - 3 | John Doe Group

Desired result (with sample data):

- tbl_result: question_ID | year | questiontext | participant_name | response

  - bp2.16 | 2012 | material cost | ACME Ltd. | 2,289,990
  - bp2.16 | 2010 | material cost | John Doe Group | 723,091
  - ...

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT tbl_responses_2010.question_ID_2010 AS Question_ID, "2010" as Year, tbl_questions_2010.questiontext, tbl_participants.participant_name,  tbl_responses_2010.response
FROM tbl_responses_2010, tbl_questions_2010, tbl_participants
WHERE tbl_responses_2010.participant_ID=tbl_participants.participant_ID AND tbl_questions_2010.question_ID_2010=tbl_responses_2010.question_ID_2010

UNION 

SELECT tbl_responses_2011.question_ID_2011 AS Question_ID, "2011" as Year, tbl_questions_2011.questiontext, tbl_participants.participant_name,  tbl_responses_2011.response
FROM tbl_responses_2011, tbl_questions_2011, tbl_participants
WHERE tbl_responses_2011.participant_ID=tbl_participants.participants_ID AND tbl_questions_2011.question_ID_2011=tbl_responses_2011.question_ID_2011

ORDER BY Question_ID, response, Year;
```

This gives me a joined table of all responses for 2011 and 2011 but having wrong question IDs for the 2010 questions. I don't know how I can map them using the field tbl_questions_2011.2010_ID

Comment: You've provided a good description of your requirements. Now what you need to do is to try writing some queries on your own. That will lead to one of two outcomes: **(1)** You'll figure it out, in which case you can answer your own question, or **(2)** You'll hit a stumbling block, in which case you can update your question with what you have so far and ask a *specific* question about it.

Comment: I'm getting only so far as to generate a joined table of all responses, but then this query will give me the wrong question IDs for 2010.

Comment: Hint: Click the "edit" link at the bottom of your question and add your updates to the question itself. That way your new information doesn't get buried in a slew of comments.